# React useRouteMatch() - Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a demo here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-p5vdeq?file=Info.tsx

I'm tryint to create a simple nested navigation.

I have a two pages Home and Info

The Info page has navigation to show components on that page.

On the Info page I'm getting an error `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

The hook is being used in a function and I'm sure I'm not breaking the hooks rules.

Can any see why I'm getting this error

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const Info: React.FC = () => {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Info</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/linkone`}>Info Link One</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/linktwo`}>Info Link Two</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/linkone`}>
          <h1>Info One</h1>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/linktwo`}>
          <h1>Info Two</h1>
        </Route>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

Comment: When I go to your provided link and update to the latest dependencies it worked. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

Comment: Updated these 2 to the latest and it worked.
 "react": "^17.0.1",
 "react-dom": "^17.0.1",